# Convert f(x1,x2,x3,x4) truth table to 4:1 multiplexer

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

How can I convert truth table of 4 variables into one 4:1 multiplexer

Here is an example how to convert it into 8:1 multiplexer

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth-table can in fact be implemented with a `2-1` multiplexer:

[image]

A minimized expression for the function depicted by the truth-table is

```
Y = X1 X3 + X3' X4
```

In words:
Output `Y` is `X1` for `X3` true. For `X3` false, `Y` is `X4`

Input `X3` selects either `X1` or `X4` to be forwarded to output `Y`.

Input `X2` is ignored (as don't care).

You could use a `4-1` multiplexer and set the lower select input to `X3`, while the higher select input is set to constant `0`.